# Can we put a vecctor inside integral?

Tags: calculus

$v$ is a column vector. Can I write like this? Is it possible that the result of integral is vector?

$$\int_{\Omega}v(x) dx $$

The domain is in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Yes. All you do is divide $v$ into it's components, integrate them all separately and then put back the components to give you another vector. That vector is the integral.

Comment: The integral of the vector is the vector of the integrals.

Answer (score 0):

A general approach (with most details omitted) is to define the integral
of a non scalar function $v$ as the value $I$ **iff** for all linear functionals $\phi$, we have $\phi(I) = \int \phi(v(x)) dx$.

This reduces the integral down to a scalar integral.

In the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$, it is sufficient to consider the
functionals $e_k^*(x) = x_k$, in which case we have
$\int v(x) dx  = \begin{bmatrix} \int v_1(x) dx \\ \vdots \\ \int v_n(x) dx \end{bmatrix}  $.

Answer (score 0):

Two remarks about domains and ranges:

1) an important amount of such integrals have $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$ as their domain instead of $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. It is the case for parameterized curves $(x(t),y(t))$.

2) the range may also be $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Of course, it is not in the same framework that you have presented your question. But there is an important notion which is $\int_{\Omega}v(x).dx$ (with a point denoting a dot product, sometimes omitted...). As a dot product is a number, its integral is in fact a number ; in this case we speak about the line integral of a vector field. See for example [this](http://www2.math.umd.edu/~jmr/241/lineint1.html#1).